# What is the recommended production deployment strategy for Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to figure out an appropriate production deployment strategy for an Apache Kafka cluster with High Availability.

I was unable to find a specific documentation which describes such a strategy. So based on the articles I found, I have come up with the following strategy.

- 3 zookeeper nodes
- 3 kafka brokers (each having a replica of all the topic partitions that I'm planning to use)
- Replication factor of 3 for each Topic
- on 3 physical machines (each having a zookeeper node and a broker node)

The reason why I have decided to have a zookeeper node and a broker node on each machine is to avoid a 'brain split' in an event of a network partitioning as described in [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825755/how-does-kafka-handle-network-partitions)

I want to know,

1. Whether there is a adverse performance impact in having both a zookeeper node and a broker node on a single machine? (and whether it would make more sense to go ahead with 6 physical machines by deploying such that each machine would either have a kafka broker or a zookeeper node?)
2. Whether the deployment strategy I have come with is suitable for a production deployment? (Or how it can be improved?)

Also, if you have come across a guide which recommends a suitable deployment configuration, kindly include its link.

Appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Three is the minimum number of brokers you'll need, but you might want more for additional redundancy and/or capacity
- Usually, people deploy their Kafka brokers and Zookeeper nodes on separate hardware.

This [Reference Architecture](https://www.confluent.io/resources/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/) should help you further.